# extract valid IP from a field in oracle DB in C

Tags: sql, c, ip

I am facing some problem in C language to extract a valid IP(v4 and v6) from oracle DB for example.

1, if the field is having a ip like : 10.2.33.4.5-34 
   I should be able to extract 10.2.33.4 only

2, if field have abc-100.2.33.4.545
   extract only 100.2.33.4

Hope there is a solution to this in C .

Thanks and Regards,
Mohib

Comment: have you tried anything?  regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str1[]="10.2.33.4.5-34"

substr(1,11,str1);

str2[]="abc-100.2.33.4.545"

substr(5,14,str2)
```

The above code should be used in C.

Comment: HI Venk
Thanks for replying but one more problem is we dont know how long the string is and where exactly is the valid ip in the field to extract.

Comment: so u mean to say u have variable length IPs right?

Comment: If u have variable lengths then u nead use a switch case and write it in C lang.. I guess its not possible with SQL

Comment: Hi Venk, Thanks again for helping out !
Let me think of a switch case implementation if there is some problem
i would require your help again.

Comment: pls vote up.. if the post is helpful..

Comment: Venk , new on the forum iam not able to vote

Comment: There is up ^ symbol on left side to my post.. u can vote up there..

Comment: @Mohib: From these comments you'd be much better off investigating a solution using Regular Expressions.  Oracle may have support for RE's built in.